# How to fix a subsetting issue in R

Tags: r

I am trying to subset my dataframe, but when I do some of the factors are not being brought in and left behind.

When I try this code it gives me a dataframe that has 2048 obs, but then when I try the next set of code I still have COW, Negative Control, and Positive Control in the subset.

```
Controls_data <- subset(data_all, SampleID == c('COW', 'Negative Control', 'Positive Control'))

Sample_data <- subset(data_all, SampleID != c("COW", "Negative Control", "Positive Control"))
```

I should have 6,144 in the Controls_data. I double checked this in excel because I thought that maybe they were spelled differently or had spaces.

Comment: Try `%in%` instead of `!=`, like `!SampleID %in% c("COW", "Negative Control", "Positive Control")`

Comment: `==` is pairwise vectorized, meaning `x == y` checks that the first element of x equals the first element of y, the second element of x equals the second element of y, etc. On the other hand `x %in% y` tests whether each element of `x` occurs anywhere in `y`.

Answer (score 0):

As @arg0naut and @Gregor both writes and suggests. Your problem is that `==` uses R's standard reuse rules and then does pairwise comparison. So that is not what you want to do.

Compare the outputs from the following lines of codes.:

```
letters == c("c", "e")
letters %in% c("c", "e")
letters == c("c", "e", "d")
```

Notice the warning the last case. In your case, the left hand side happens to be a multiple of the right and you are not warned.

You could also use the `match` function in your case:

```
match(c("c", "e", "d"), letters)
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the %in% function to work for me, but I couldn't get the match function to work properly.